# Decoding ciphertext encoded in the Affine Cipher

Tags: python, encryption

In my Discrete Mathematics course our professor wants us to decode the string encoded in the Affine Cipher;

> *"8YM8FlYPiiMl.YP[eYWP[P[P."

However, we do not know the keys, or modulus used, so I'm not sure how to decode it except without using a brute force attack method and increment my keys and mods using nested for loops. My friend and I have been scanning outputs looking for the answer;
[output results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue2AP.png)  - Would appreciate the help of an expert.

Here is my code for the Affine Cipher as well.

```
def chars_to_nums(c):
    nums = []
    for i in c:
        nums.append(ord(i)-32)
    return nums



def nums_to_chars(n):
    chars = ""
    for i in n:
        chars = chars + chr(i+32)
    return chars
```

ENCODE:

```
def affine_encode(plaintext, a, b, m):
  charNum = chars_to_nums(plaintext)
  for x in range(len(charNum)):
    charNum[x] = (a * charNum[x] + b) % m
  result = nums_to_chars(charNum)
  return result

print(affine_encode("HELLO", 7, 23, 95)
```

DECODE:

```
def affine_decode(ciphertext, a, b, m):
  charNum=chars_to_nums(ciphertext)
  c=m-1
  inverse=0
  for x1 in range(c):
    Ainv=(x1*a)%m
    if Ainv==1:
      inverse=x1
      break
  for x2 in range(len(charNum)):
    charNum[x2]=(inverse*(charNum[x2]-b)) % m
  result=nums_to_chars(charNum)
  return result
print(affine_decode("2|NNc", 7, 23, 95))
```

Comment: One method would be to determine the [index of coincidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_coincidence) of each possible option, and sort by how comparable they are to the English language. Another possible option would be to search for [common bigrams or trigrams](http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/letter-frequencies-various-languages/english-letter-frequencies/) in the English language.

Comment: As for the modulus, that should be known or at least easy to estimate, as the ciphertext is likely to contain characters which are close to the top and bottom of the character range allowed.

Comment: Thank you! That definitely helps a lot.

Comment: Your code has a serious bug. You define `c=m-1`, which prevents your code from finding the inverse of *m - 1* (mod *m*). Instead of throwing an error (like with `assert inverse > 0`), it will just use `inverse = 0` while attempting to decrypt each character.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if you're aware, but the `*"` at the beginning and the `"` at the end of your quoted string are not actually part of the ciphertext. Treating them as such might make the plaintext harder to find.